# HTML processor add invalid code

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm processing some html code which has some JavaScript code inside. The processor automatically add slash (`\`) before every closing html tag in JavaScript. So I'm trying to replace the terms like `<\/a>` or `<\/li>` in my JavaScript code with valid HTML closing tag such as `</a>` and `</li>` respectively using php preg_replace() function. How can I do that?

The current code look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("ol").append("<li>list item <a href='#' class='remove'>x<\/a><\/li>"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That almost seems intentional, if it's only doing this with end tags that appear in JavaScript elements.

Comment: The HTML string is appended to the `document` without issues

Comment: Thanks but i'm showing that code in browser after some formatting and not executing that's why i want to remove this to avoid confusion. Please suggest some regex to replace this.